# getting mvc index and details for to display an actual value vs an ID value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

yeah the question is: can mcv display on the details and index form the text data values vs just ID value that gets stored in the database .

It seems that mvc is very limited in what it can display to the screen. All of the demos and tutorials seem to stop short of showing this is a possibility most just show the user typing in the the full text value. So for example the user has a user interface form that has a list of values drop down element. THey click the value and the ID gets stored to the database.

Later on recall the user wants to pull the data back up for review... in mvc it seems you are stuck with displaying the ID field in the textbox.

but in most other systems you can make a datatable and return the text value of the field back to the form... Is this possible with MVC or are you  limited to saving the full text value to the the database?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZIFQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq5d6.png)

Comment: Just include the object from `TestTable` in your query and display the name property

Comment: hi Stephen can you point me to an example? I can't find out how to to this which is why I decided to try here on stack exchange. You say include the object from test table... I don't know what you mean by that sadly.  In mvc the wizard has created a form called index and one called details. In the  create form I have stored this data into a storage table that is not the test table... the testTable contains the list of values... that the user selects. The ID gets stored to the table not the long description text because I thought there would be a way to get the text to display in on these forms

Comment: And to the guys that are marking the question with minus.. if you can't answer the question do mark it minus.... you are just messing up the guys that is asking the question. IF you don't like it move on. Don't kill the guys asking it!! Thanks!

Comment: No one can answer this because you have not given any information about your models or the database structure (hence the downvotes) - Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Stephen Muecke, Question seems pretty clear to me... I even added pictures... so the question is VERY clear. But I was able to find the answer on my own, thanks and I will answer my own QA. The true reason people don't answer the question is because of the Stackoverflow culture.. . if you have time to downvote you have time to answer the question. It's just all so silly some of the people and how they operate here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah the answer is: Make a view in SQL Server and then Link that View to the application via the EDMX. Details below.

Finally!  I was able to figure out and I will post the solution so that it may help some one get around the mvc / normalized database limitation that seems to exist when you try to follow some of the tutorials.

The key is to build a SQL view outside of MVC. This can then be linked to the application and it will appear to be a table.

So if you use the database first method and you are using SQL server you will need to simply make a view in SQL server. This take mvcs out of the picture all and is much easier.

Step 1: Make a SQL view... that has everything you need joined in one big super view for what you need to display.

So in my case  I made a sql server view that has the storage table linked to the support tables. Think of the query builder in MS Access where you link your tables to make a query.

You draw out your tables and links.

Add that to your Database First EDMX and in your controller use that new super view... and in your index and details forms you change the @model to your new super sql view and change the field name in the textboxfor... Boom problem solved... pretty swell how it all works... in this way you don't have to build some complicated view model. You just take the class that the wizard builds and then make a partial class to rename fields to give them user friendly names.

And you are no longer limited by mvc limitations

hope this helps!